# Automate "Vlookup" using Sharepoint Lists, and Flow

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have two lists in sharepoint. List A (Template) and B(population). List A contains column "Employee Login ID" and List B contains "Employee_PrimaryLoginID".

I want to create a vlookup, So whenever a new record in List A gets created, a column named "Submitted" will be edited in List B.

I want to lookup on "Employee Login ID" and ""Employee_PrimaryLoginID" , as "Employee_PrimaryLoginID" in List B is the full set, and when a new record is created(in list A) I want to be able to view that is have been created.

Hopefully this makes sense. Here is what I have tried using Flow:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding:

- ListA contains column "Employee Login ID"
- ListB contains "Employee_PrimaryLoginID" and "Submitted". And ListB has all employees’ login ID, in other words "Employee_PrimaryLoginID" in ListB is the full set.
- When ListA creates a new item, if "Employee Login ID" is equal to "Employee_PrimaryLoginID", then update the corresponding item in ListB and set the "Submitted" value to the value of "Employee Login ID".

**If yes, please following steps:**

1.Set "Employee Login ID" in ListA is unique value and required column

[image]

2.Set "Employee_PrimaryLoginID" in ListB is unique value and required column

[image]

3.Create Microsoft Flow

[image]

4.Save and Test flow

5.When you creating new item, the ListB will happen as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there to also update list B with existing values in List A? I notice this only works for new entries.

Comment: Had a question, must column name be required and unique value?